# If using an adjusted F value (repeated measures ANOVA), should partial eta squared be adjusted?

Tags: anova, effect-size

I am using a procedure which, due to reducing error variance and resulting in artificially inflated F-values, requires the calculated F-value to be divided by (N-1)^2. The sources I have regarding this method only refer to adjusting test statistics such as F , t , and r values.

The associated p-values are of course simply looked up for the relevant F and degrees of freedom.

But what about effect sizes?

When reporting my analyses, my effect sizes appear unusually large (i.e. all are partial eta squared > .9) - am I right to think that these are artificially inflated as the F values are? If so, how do I deal with this?

Answer (score 0):

You can always calculate an $eta^2$ of some sort (partial or full, depending on design) directly from the F-value using:

$[partial] eta^2 = \frac{dfN*F}{(dfN*F + dfE)}$

So, if you had to shrink your F for some reason, you could use this formula to calculate the new value of eta-squared.

Comment: It is not clear what you are saying that answers the question.

Comment: This is not an answer.